# How to share a directory with the host without networking in QEMU?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, qemu

My problem is that networking devices in my device tree are not very stable so I thought the best way to share a folder between qemu and the host system is mount the same img without cache on both sides but the -hda option on qemu does not make the hd available in /dev/.

Here is the command I run.

```
./qemu-xilinx/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M xilinx-zynq-a9 -m 1024 -serial null -serial mon:stdio -dtb resources/devicetree.dtb -kernel resources/zImage -initrd resources.qemu/ramdisk.img -nographic -s
```

So the question is: is there a way to avoid networking and yet have a shared directory between qemu and the host?

EDIT: I compiled with

```
./configure --target-list="arm-softmmu,microblazeel-softmmu" --enable-fdt --disable-kvm --enable-virtfs
```

which should enable anything needed. However when I run

```
./qemu-xilinx/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M xilinx-zynq-a9 -m 1024 -serial null -serial mon:stdio -dtb /homes/cperivol/Sandbox/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/resources/devicetree.dtb -kernel /homes/cperivol/Sandbox/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/resources/zImage -initrd /homes/cperivol/Sandbox/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/resources.qemu/ramdisk.img -nographic -s -fsdev local,path=/homes/cperivol/Sandbox/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/qemu-sandbox/,security_model=passthrough,id=host0 -device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=host0,mount_tag=host_tag0
```

or

```
./qemu-xilinx/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M xilinx-zynq-a9 -m 1024 -serial null -serial mon:stdio -dtb resources/devicetree.dtb -kernel resources/zImage -initrd resources.qemu/ramdisk.img -nographic -s -virtfs local,path=/homes/cperivol/Sandbox/xilinx-zynq-bootstrap/qemu-sandbox/,mount_tag=host0,security_model=passthrough,id=host0
```

I get

```
No 'PCI' bus found for device 'virtio-9p-pci'
```

Maybe I should also mention that in `arm-softmmu/config-devices.mak` there is `CONFIG_PCI=y`, and sure enough the object files of the pci are there in `hw/pci`.

EDIT2: Looking at the device tree as dumped by qemu the emulated system does not include a PCI bus.

```
(qemu) info qtree
bus: main-system-bus
  type System
  dev: xlnx.ps7-dev-cfg, id ""
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000f8007000/000000000000011c
  dev: pl330, id ""
    gpio-in 32
    num_chnls = 8
    num_periph_req = 4
    num_events = 16
    mgr_ns_at_rst = 0
    i-cache_len = 4
    num_i-cache_lines = 8
    boot_addr = 0
    INS = 0
    PNS = 0
    data_width = 64
    wr_cap = 8
    wr_q_dep = 16
    rd_cap = 8
    rd_q_dep = 16
    data_buffer_dep = 256
    irq 17
    mmio 00000000f8003000/0000000000001000
  dev: generic-sdhci, id ""
    capareg = 0x5780080
    maxcurr = 0x0
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0101000/0000000000000100
  dev: generic-sdhci, id ""
    capareg = 0x5780080
    maxcurr = 0x0
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0100000/0000000000000100
  dev: cadence_gem, id ""
    mac = 52:54:00:12:34:56
    vlan = 0
    netdev = hub0port0
    bootindex = -1
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e000b000/0000000000000640
  dev: cadence_ttc, id ""
    irq 3
    mmio 00000000f8002000/0000000000001000
  dev: cadence_ttc, id ""
    irq 3
    mmio 00000000f8001000/0000000000001000
  dev: cadence_uart, id ""
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0001000/0000000000001000
  dev: cadence_uart, id ""
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0000000/0000000000001000
  dev: xlnx.ps7-qspi, id ""
    num-busses = 2
    num-ss-bits = 1
    num-txrx-bytes = 4
    irq 3
    mmio 00000000e000d000/0000000000000100
    mmio 00000000fc000000/0000000002000000
    bus: spi1
      type SSI
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
    bus: spi0
      type SSI
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
  dev: xlnx.ps7-spi, id ""
    num-busses = 1
    num-ss-bits = 4
    num-txrx-bytes = 1
    irq 5
    mmio 00000000e0007000/0000000000000100
    bus: spi0
      type SSI
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
  dev: xlnx.ps7-spi, id ""
    num-busses = 1
    num-ss-bits = 4
    num-txrx-bytes = 1
    irq 5
    mmio 00000000e0006000/0000000000000100
    bus: spi0
      type SSI
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
      dev: n25q128, id ""
        gpio-in 1
  dev: xlnx,ps7-usb, id "zynq-usb-1"
    maxframes = 128
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0003000/0000000000001000
    bus: zynq-usb-1.0
      type usb-bus
  dev: xlnx,ps7-usb, id "zynq-usb-0"
    maxframes = 128
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0002000/0000000000001000
    bus: zynq-usb-0.0
      type usb-bus
  dev: xlnx.ps7-i2c, id ""
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0005000/000000000000002c
    bus: i2c
      type i2c-bus
      dev: pca9548, id ""
        chip-enable = 0
        address = 0
        address-range = 128
        reg = 0
        bus: i2c@7
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@6
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@5
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@4
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@3
          type i2c-bus
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 84
            address-range = 4
            reg = 84
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 80
            address-range = 4
            reg = 80
        bus: i2c@2
          type i2c-bus
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 84
            address-range = 4
            reg = 84
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 80
            address-range = 4
            reg = 80
        bus: i2c@1
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@0
          type i2c-bus
  dev: xlnx.ps7-i2c, id ""
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000e0004000/000000000000002c
    bus: i2c
      type i2c-bus
      dev: pca9548, id ""
        chip-enable = 0
        address = 0
        address-range = 128
        reg = 0
        bus: i2c@7
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@6
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@5
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@4
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@3
          type i2c-bus
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 84
            address-range = 4
            reg = 84
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 80
            address-range = 4
            reg = 80
        bus: i2c@2
          type i2c-bus
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 84
            address-range = 4
            reg = 84
          dev: at.24c08, id ""
            size = 1024
            address = 80
            address-range = 4
            reg = 80
        bus: i2c@1
          type i2c-bus
        bus: i2c@0
          type i2c-bus
  dev: arm_mptimer, id ""
    num-cpu = 1
    irq 1
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000020
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000020
  dev: arm_mptimer, id ""
    num-cpu = 1
    irq 1
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000020
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000020
  dev: a9-scu, id ""
    num-cpu = 1
    irq 0
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000100
  dev: arm_gic, id ""
    gpio-in 96
    num-cpu = 1
    num-irq = 96
    revision = 1
    irq 1
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000001000
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000100
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000100
  dev: a9mpcore_priv, id ""
    gpio-in 64
    num-cpu = 1
    num-irq = 96
    irq 1
    mmio 00000000f8f00000/0000000000002000
  dev: xilinx,zynq_slcr, id ""
    irq 0
    mmio 00000000f8000000/0000000000001000
  dev: nand, id ""
    manufacturer_id = 32
    chip_id = 170
    drive = <null>
    irq 0
  dev: cfi.pflash02, id ""
    drive = <null>
    num-blocks = 512
    sector-length = 131072
    width = 1
    mappings = 1
    big-endian = 0
    id0 = 102
    id1 = 34
    id2 = 0
    id3 = 0
    unlock-addr0 = 2730
    unlock-addr1 = 1365
    name = "pl353.pflash"
    irq 0
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000004000000
  dev: arm.pl35x, id ""
    x = 3
    irq 0
    mmio 00000000e000e000/0000000000001000
    mmio 00000000e2000000/0000000001000000
    mmio 00000000e1000000/0000000001000000
```

Answer (score 27):

If the guest has 9p support (like Linux, or of course, Plan 9) and virtio, try adding the following switch.

```
-virtfs local,path=/path/to/share,mount_tag=host0,security_model=passthrough,id=host0
```

You may want to change the security_model parameter. See man page, qemu(1) for that. **If** I recall correctly, mount_tag is what the guest sees, leaving id as a dummy.

Make sure that the path is under the chroot if you are chrooting. It's a path to the directory on the host.

The fstab entry on the guest should look like this.

```
host0   /wherever    9p      trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L   0 0
```

Either add that to your fstab, or invoke the appropriate command manually or using your init system, whatever it may be.

Comment: Is the /path/to/share a path to a directory or the image?
Also I think it is unrelated: i get `qemu-system-arm: -virtfs local,path=/path/to/share,mount_tag=host0,security_model=passthrough,id=host0: Parameter 'driver' expects device type`

Comment: it's to the *directory* you want to share.

Comment: Also, can you confirm that the version of qemu that you're using has been built with 9p/virtfs support please? See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1130769).

Comment: good question, how do I check that?

Comment: At runtime, from your qemu binary, I wouldn't know. You'd have to check your distribution's build scripts. That is distro-specific. For example, on Arch Linux, it's the flags present **and not present**, passed to configure, in the PKGBUILD.

Comment: I built it from this source ( https://github.com/Xilinx/qemu ). `./configure' '--target-list=arm-softmmu,microblazeel-softmmu' '--enable-fdt' '--disable-kvm`. From what i see in `hq/9pfs` there are no `.o` files so I guess it was not. I will try to recompile :D

Comment: Compiled correctly I think this time. See edits.

Comment: Odd. It should be supported, at least on the version of Qemu that I have here (1.5.2 from upstream). `name "virtio-9p-pci", bus PCI` is in the list of devices reported by `qemu-system-arm -M xilinx-zynq-a9 -device '?'`. My system will incidentally have a PCI bus, but I'm emulating an i386. I'm not too sure now about your particular one. I'm currently at loss.

Answer (score 8):

**Minimalist working 9P Buildroot setup for x86_64, arm and aarch64**

I have created a [highly automated Buildroot working setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/82fab09e1ec0e9b1931eba81f2974b8c8c7b41b9#9p) that might help you diff out why your approach is not working.

The main ingredients are:

- kernel settings:

  ```
  CONFIG_9P_FS=y
  CONFIG_9P_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
  CONFIG_9P_FS_SECURITY=y
  CONFIG_NETWORK_FILESYSTEMS=y
  CONFIG_NET_9P=y
  CONFIG_NET_9P_DEBUG=y
  CONFIG_NET_9P_VIRTIO=y
  ```

  For aarch64, also add:

  ```
  CONFIG_PCI=y
  CONFIG_PCI_HOST_COMMON=y
  CONFIG_PCI_HOST_GENERIC=y
  CONFIG_VIRTIO_PCI=y
  CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=y
  CONFIG_VIRTIO_NET=y
  ```

  If you forget to add the aarch64 configs, and `mount` fails with:

  ```
  mount: mounting host0 on /mnt/my9p failed: Invalid argument
  ```

  and dmesg complains with:

  ```
  9pnet_virtio: no channels available for device
  ```

  Documented at: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup
- my fstab entry and QEMU command were exactly as explained at: https://superuser.com/a/628381/128124

  The manual mount command is:

  ```
  mkdir /mnt/my9p
  mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L host0 /mnt/my9p
  ```

  where `host0` is the tag specified on the QEMU CLI.

  For reference, my full QEMU command lines are: x86:

  ```
  ./buildroot/output.x86_64~/host/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -m 128M \
  -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait \
  -netdev user,hostfwd=tcp::45455-:45455,id=net0 \
  -smp 1 \
  -virtfs local,path=/host/path/to/share,mount_tag=host0,security_model=mapped,id=host0  \
  -M pc \
  -append 'root=/dev/vda nopat nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y' \
  -device edu \
  -device lkmc_pci_min \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0 \
  -kernel ./buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/bzImage    \
  -drive file='./buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2'
  ```

  arm:

  ```
  ./buildroot/output.arm~/host/usr/bin/qemu-system-arm -m 128M -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait -netdev user,hostfwd=tcp::45455-:45455,id=net0 -smp 1 -virtfs local,path=/host/path/to/share,mount_tag=host0,security_model=mapped,id=host0  -M versatilepb -append 'root=/dev/sda nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y' -device rtl8139,netdev=net0 -dtb ./buildroot/output.arm~/images/versatile-pb.dtb -kernel ./buildroot/output.arm~/images/zImage -serial stdio    -drive file='./buildroot/output.arm~/images/rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=scsi,format=qcow2'
  ```

  aarch64:

  ```
  ./buildroot/output.aarch64~/host/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 -m 128M -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait -netdev user,hostfwd=tcp::45455-:45455,id=net0 -smp 1 -virtfs local,path=/host/path/to/share,mount_tag=host0,security_model=mapped,id=host0  -M virt -append 'root=/dev/sda nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y' -cpu cortex-a57 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 -kernel ./buildroot/output.aarch64~/images/Image -nographic -serial stdio
  ```

  Ensure QEMU is built with:

  ```
  ./configure --enable-virtfs
  ```

Tested on QEMU 2.11 and guest Linux kernel 4.15.

I then also tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and it just worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792

Comment: worked for me. pay attention to "The main ingredients are".... it sometimes hard to find where and what you need to enable in order to enable those ingredients. you can check each time in the .config file if you managed to enable all of them...

Comment: this only works for transferring/sharing from host to vm. when tryed to add file to the folder from the vm I get "Operation not permitted"

Comment: @yehudahs I don't reproduce on the Ubuntu setup described at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792 I was able to add files both ways just now. Let me know if you find something out.

Comment: I'm running KVM-OSX, I'm not sure where to add the kernel settings.

Comment: @jasxir that repo runs MacOS in QEMU right? `CONFIG_9P_FS=` is a Linux kernel setting as I'm running LInux in QEMU. So you have to find if MacOS has 9P support. This has some mentions: https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2019/06/macos-qemu-guest/

Comment: Thank you. I got it running, I think 9p is supported by default in Mac, just had to use virt manager for that.

Comment: Works perfectly, just would like to add that if someone built Qemu from source, they need to use `--enable-virtfs` in the configuration to ensure the fs is supported